# SVG animateTransform with scale and transform origin in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg element that I would like to scale and have it scale from bottom to top.

Here is a codepen example: https://codepen.io/knightjdr/pen/QQeNOj

I achieve the scaling with animateTransform and have it scale from bottom to top by moving the origin. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari where it scales from the top left.

Support for transform-origin with svg in Safari is unknown according to Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin), but it looks like it is not supported from my example.

I'm looking either for a way to fix this in Safari or an alternative way of achieving this scaling effect if anyone has a suggestion.

Here is the abbreviated code from codepen:

```
.steam {
   -webkit-transform-origin: 93px 130px;
}

<svg>
   <g class="steam">
      <path
        fill="#763626"
        d="..."
      />
      <path
         fill="#AC867C"
         d="..."
      />
      <animateTransform
         additive="sum"
         attributeName="transform"
         begin="0"
         dur="2"
         from="0 0"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         to="1 1"
         type="scale"
      />
   </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform-origin property does have good support in all browsers, so why not do your animation outside the SVG? Also, by adding viewBox and preserveAspectRatio to your SVG element, you can control the size of the viewBox and make sure that the transform happens directly from the center of the element.

Tested on Safari and it works perfectly.

Demo below:

```css
svg {
  max-height: 100vh;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation: steam-animation 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes steam-animation {
  0%   { transform: scale(0,0); opacity: 0;}
  100% { transform: scale(1,1); opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 175 150" preserveAspectRation="xMinYMin">
  <g class="steam">
    <path
       fill="#763626"
       d="M138.422,14.336c-8.441,0-16.208,2.682-22.398,7.174C112.494,9.193,98.66,0,82.121,0C71.58,0,62.141,3.738,55.762,9.634c-4.618-1.997-9.784-3.118-15.239-3.118c-19.607,0-35.502,14.441-35.502,32.255c0,7.312,2.682,14.053,7.195,19.463C4.667,61.181,0,65.241,0,69.725c0,8.997,18.785,16.291,41.957,16.291c13.149,0,24.88-2.35,32.573-6.025c5.51,5.703,13.458,9.283,22.294,9.283c9.634,0,18.205-4.261,23.719-10.884c5.288,2.777,11.383,4.368,17.879,4.368c20.201,
0,36.578-15.316,36.578-34.21S158.624,14.336,138.422,14.336z"
    />
    <path
      fill="#AC867C"
      d="M160.967,55.897c0-14.556-10.783-26.355-24.085-26.355c-6.238,0-11.923,2.595-16.201,6.853c-5.278-4.719-13.404-7.747-22.525-7.747c-4.029,0-7.862,
0.592-11.344,1.657c-4.261-1.628-9.067-2.55-14.158-2.55c-17.475,0-31.642,10.8-31.642,24.122c0,3.975,1.269,7.722,3.503,11.028c-12.563,2.494-21.449,8.614-21.449,15.774c0,9.375,15.224,16.975,34.003,16.975c7.695,0,14.79-1.277,20.488-3.429c5.172,5.813,14.364,9.683,24.849,9.683c13.623,0,25.072-6.53,28.342-15.373c0.756,0.116,1.542,0.185,2.355,0.185c4.958,0,9.055-2.296,9.789-5.294C153.286,78.504,160.967,68.182,160.967,55.897z"
    />
    <line
       fill="none"
       stroke="#763626"
       stroke-width="4"
       stroke-miterlimit="10"
       x1="91.474"
       y1="74.599"
       x2="91.474"
       y2="125"
    />
    <line
       fill="none"
       stroke="#763626"
       stroke-width="4"
       stroke-miterlimit="10"
       x1="61.647"
       y1="83.668"
       x2="82.528"
       y2="125"
    />
    <line
       fill="none"
       stroke="#763626"
       stroke-width="4"
       stroke-miterlimit="10"
       x1="121.3"
       y1="83.668"
       x2="100.419"
       y2="125"
    />
  </g>
</svg>
```